# Why environment variable substitution does not work in bash in this case?

Tags: bash, osx

I am trying to set the ENV variable just for the scope of this command

```
ENV=dev echo terraform plan -state=$ENV.tfstate -var-file=$ENV.tfvars -out=$ENV.plan
```

the output is for some reason:

```
 terraform plan -state=.tfstate -var-file=.tfvars -out=.plan
```

Why is it?

I am using `bash` in osx mojave